# tensorflow execution failure Library not loaded:libcublas.8.0.dylib on Mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am just validating my tensorflow [installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#ValidateYourInstallation) on my MacBook Air when i add import statement on python console, I am getting below error.

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/arpitrastogi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Reason: image not found


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Below are my system configurations:

```
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (x86_64)
```

/usr/local/lib is :

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       44 Aug 24 18:43 libHalf.12.dylib -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libHalf.12.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       37 Aug 24 18:43 libHalf.a -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libHalf.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       41 Aug 24 18:43 libHalf.dylib -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libHalf.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       47 Aug 24 18:43 libIex-2_2.12.dylib -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libIex-2_2.12.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       36 Aug 24 18:43 libIex.a -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libIex.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       40 Aug 24 18:43 libIex.dylib -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libIex.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       51 Aug 24 18:43 libIexMath-2_2.12.dylib -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libIexMath-2_2.12.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       40 Aug 24 18:43 libIexMath.a -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libIexMath.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       44 Aug 24 18:43 libIexMath.dylib -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libIexMath.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       50 Aug 24 18:43 libIlmImf-2_2.22.dylib -> ../Cellar/openexr/2.2.0/lib/libIlmImf-2_2.22.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       39 Aug 24 18:43 libIlmImf.a -> ../Cellar/openexr/2.2.0/lib/libIlmImf.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       43 Aug 24 18:43 libIlmImf.dylib -> ../Cellar/openexr/2.2.0/lib/libIlmImf.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       54 Aug 24 18:43 libIlmImfUtil-2_2.22.dylib -> ../Cellar/openexr/2.2.0/lib/libIlmImfUtil-2_2.22.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       43 Aug 24 18:43 libIlmImfUtil.a -> ../Cellar/openexr/2.2.0/lib/libIlmImfUtil.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       47 Aug 24 18:43 libIlmImfUtil.dylib -> ../Cellar/openexr/2.2.0/lib/libIlmImfUtil.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       53 Aug 24 18:43 libIlmThread-2_2.12.dylib -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libIlmThread-2_2.12.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       42 Aug 24 18:43 libIlmThread.a -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libIlmThread.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       46 Aug 24 18:43 libIlmThread.dylib -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libIlmThread.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       49 Aug 24 18:43 libImath-2_2.12.dylib -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libImath-2_2.12.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       38 Aug 24 18:43 libImath.a -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libImath.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       42 Aug 24 18:43 libImath.dylib -> ../Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0/lib/libImath.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       37 Aug 24 18:43 libjpeg.9.dylib -> ../Cellar/jpeg/9b/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       31 Aug 24 18:43 libjpeg.a -> ../Cellar/jpeg/9b/lib/libjpeg.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       35 Aug 24 18:43 libjpeg.dylib -> ../Cellar/jpeg/9b/lib/libjpeg.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root          wheel  2037160 Nov  9  2015 libmlrxapi1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root          wheel   759232 Nov  9  2015 libmwebsvc1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       70 Aug 30 19:34 libopencv_flann -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_flann.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       36 Aug 24 18:43 libpng.a -> ../Cellar/libpng/1.6.31/lib/libpng.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       40 Aug 24 18:43 libpng.dylib -> ../Cellar/libpng/1.6.31/lib/libpng.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       45 Aug 24 18:43 libpng16.16.dylib -> ../Cellar/libpng/1.6.31/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       38 Aug 24 18:43 libpng16.a -> ../Cellar/libpng/1.6.31/lib/libpng16.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       42 Aug 24 18:43 libpng16.dylib -> ../Cellar/libpng/1.6.31/lib/libpng16.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       38 Aug 24 18:44 libtbb.dylib -> ../Cellar/tbb/2017_U7/lib/libtbb.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       44 Aug 24 18:44 libtbbmalloc.dylib -> ../Cellar/tbb/2017_U7/lib/libtbbmalloc.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       50 Aug 24 18:44 libtbbmalloc_proxy.dylib -> ../Cellar/tbb/2017_U7/lib/libtbbmalloc_proxy.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       45 Aug 24 18:43 libtiff.5.dylib -> ../Cellar/libtiff/4.0.8_3/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       39 Aug 24 18:43 libtiff.a -> ../Cellar/libtiff/4.0.8_3/lib/libtiff.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       43 Aug 24 18:43 libtiff.dylib -> ../Cellar/libtiff/4.0.8_3/lib/libtiff.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       47 Aug 24 18:43 libtiffxx.5.dylib -> ../Cellar/libtiff/4.0.8_3/lib/libtiffxx.5.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       41 Aug 24 18:43 libtiffxx.a -> ../Cellar/libtiff/4.0.8_3/lib/libtiffxx.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       45 Aug 24 18:43 libtiffxx.dylib -> ../Cellar/libtiff/4.0.8_3/lib/libtiffxx.dylib
drwxrwxr-x   6 arpitrastogi  admin      204 Jun 19 14:19 node_modules
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       72 Aug 30 19:29 opencv_calib3d -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_calib3d.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       69 Aug 30 19:31 opencv_core -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_core.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       68 Aug 30 19:32 opencv_dnn -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_dnn.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       75 Aug 30 19:33 opencv_features2d -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_features2d.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       70 Aug 30 19:35 opencv_flann -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_flann.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       72 Aug 30 19:35 opencv_highgui -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_highgui.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       74 Aug 30 19:35 opencv_imgcodecs -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       72 Aug 30 19:36 opencv_imgproc -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_imgproc.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       67 Aug 30 19:36 opencv_ml -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_ml.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       74 Aug 30 19:37 opencv_objdetect -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_objdetect.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       70 Aug 30 19:37 opencv_photo -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_photo.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       70 Aug 30 19:37 opencv_shape -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_shape.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       74 Aug 30 19:37 opencv_stitching -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_stitching.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       73 Aug 30 19:38 opencv_superres -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_superres.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       70 Aug 30 19:38 opencv_video -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_video.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       72 Aug 30 19:39 opencv_videoio -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_videoio.3.3.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arpitrastogi  admin       74 Aug 30 19:39 opencv_videostab -> /Users/arpitrastogi/scrap/opencv_build/lib/libopencv_videostab.3.3.0.dylib
drwxr-xr-x   7 arpitrastogi  admin      238 Aug 24 18:43 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x   3 arpitrastogi  admin      102 Aug 24 18:44 python2.7
```

I am running it on Mac in combination with opencv.